# Drupal Views pager shows last page when higher pager value is entered manually instead of page not found

Tags: views, paging

I have a view with pager. The views pager is not AJAX and the pager id comes is the URL as
`http://d7.local?page=3`
There are total of 15 pages in the view.
So the last page is `http://d7.local?page=14`
Now if I manually enter a pager number which is higher that 14 say 30 it redirects to the last page
Need to redirect the user to a 404 page under this situation.

Comment: It doesn't 'redirect' to the last page - the calculation of `current_page_num * num_per_page` is the upper limit of the range in the query, so 14 * 10 = 140: `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 140`. Similarly 30 * 10 = 300: `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 300`, which for a table with <= 140 records will produce the same resultset. What you're looking at is by design, I'm not sure there's an easy way to get around it

Comment: But in my case its showing the results from the last page. I guess normally it should show a blank page.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the point I was making. It's _supposed_ to show the results from the last page (see the above comment for the full explanation). What you're seeing is the expected behaviour of the module

Comment: Ohkk.. any idea how to overrode this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way out!!..
I used theme_pager and global variable $pager_total

Here is the code

```
/**
 * Implements theme_pager
 */
function theme_pager($variables) {
  global $pager_total;
  if ($_GET['page'] > $pager_total[0]) {
    drupal_not_found();
    exit;
  }
}
```